# Pandas Aggregate price and calculate weights/weightage of that of price vs volume data and group by step of 5 prices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
       price   volume
0     100.0     2500
1     100.5     4100
2     101.0     2311
3     101.5     5066
4     102.0     9585
...    ...       ...
```

I want to first get a grouping of price and sum the volumes with a step of 5.
For example (using random values):

```
       price   volume
0     100.0     15000
1     105.0     12000
2     110.0     19000
3     115.0     30000
4     120.0     21000
...    ...       ...
```

and finally based on individual volume and price I want to give each price a weight/weighted average/score so I can standardise the data to know which volume has the most weight.
For example:

```
       price   volume     weight   
0     100.0     15000        3  
1     105.0     12000       2.5
2     110.0     19000       3.5
3     115.0     30000       5
4     120.0     21000       4
...    ...       ...
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: what falls in price 100 (anything > 95 and <= 100), what falls in price 105

Comment: yes, 100 will include the sum of volumes from >95 to <=100, 105 will include sum of volume of >100 to <=105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the standard way to round the price so 97.5 to 102.49 will be in group 100.
Weight - I have used simple formula as evident.

data.csv:

```
price   volume
100.0     2500
103.5     4100
101.0     2311
105.5     5066
109.0     9585
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter='\s+')
print(df)
df['price_grp'] = np.around(df.price.values/5, decimals=0)*5
df['tot_vol'] = df.groupby('price_grp')['volume'].transform('sum')
df['weight'] = np.around(df['volume'] / df['tot_vol'], decimals=2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   price  volume
0  100.0    2500
1  103.5    4100
2  101.0    2311
3  105.5    5066
4  109.0    9585
   price  volume  price_grp  tot_vol  weight
0  100.0    2500      100.0     4811    0.52
1  103.5    4100      105.0     9166    0.45
2  101.0    2311      100.0     4811    0.48
3  105.5    5066      105.0     9166    0.55
4  109.0    9585      110.0     9585    1.00
```